# how to get the balance of each participant from transfer table using one select query?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a transfer table which looks like this:

[transfer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUd0n.png)

[image]

I would like to get the balance of each participant from the transfer table.

The output of the query should looks like this:

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAAfE.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try with something like this:

```
select sender,(select sum(amount)
               from table1 b
               where b.recipient=a.sender)-sum(amount)
from table1 a
group by sender
```

Where you get for every sender the sum of the amount he has given as a sender minus the sum of the amount he has got as receiver.

**EDIT** 
Some one told me that the sum was inverted and he was right, so I changed the order of the operands

Comment: I think you have the sum inverted. the sender part should be negative

Comment: @Juan Carlos Oropeza You are right, i have just modified it

Comment: The problem with this aproach is if a person only receive but never send (selfish bastard) wont appear on the result

Answer (score 1):

Using `UNION ALL` and `group by`

```
select person, sum(b)
from
(
  select sender person, -amount b from transfer
  union all
  select recipient person, amount b from transfer
) t 
group by person
```

So every transaction is treated as a decrease and increase of balance if the person is sender and recipient, respectively.